# Integral on real line computed expressly via contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I have to compute $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{(x^2+1)(x+1)^{3/2}}\,dx$.

I know that with a change of variables I could make it become the integral of a rational function, but I want expressly to evaluate the integral through contour integration in the complex plane (for example if instead of $3/2$ I had an irrational number, the change of variables wouldn't work).

I was able to compute similar integrals using a keyhole contour that went around the branch points. In those cases, though, the non-integer power was at the numerator, or if at the denominator, it was less than 1. The problem with this one is that I can't bound the function near the branch point in such a way that the small circle integral around it goes to zero as the radius goes to zero. 
What should I do? Is there a completely different technique to handle this one? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doing by contour integration the integral $\int_{-1}^\infty$ is more likely  to be possible, since $-1$ is a branch point.  But $0$ is not a special point of this integrand, so (as a guess) $\int_0^\infty$ is not possible to do by contour integration.

Comment: Ouch. Ok, but if the exponent was $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $\frac{3}{2}$ I really can't imagine a single way to compute the integral...that is not by numerical aoproximation.

Comment: Maple does $\int_0^\infty x^2 dx/((1+x^2)(1+x)^\alpha), \alpha > 1,$ in terms of the Meijer G function.